# Viewing unique fields

Tags: juttle

Is there a juttle program I can run to view all unique fields within a given query? I'm trying comb through a list of events of the same type that have a ton of different fields.

I know I could just use the `@table` sink and scroll right but, I'd like to view unique fields in a list if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky but works:

```
events -from :5 minutes ago: -to :now: | head 1 | @logger -display.style 'pretty'
```

You get:

```
{
"bytes"       : 7745,
"status"      : "200",
"user_agent"  : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 511 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3",
"version"     : "1.1",
"ctry"        : "US",
"ident"       : "-",
"message"     : "194.97.17.121 - - [2014-02-25T09:00:00-08:00] \"GET /black\" 200 7745 \"http://google.co.in/\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 511 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3\"",
"auth"        : "-",
"verb"        : "GET",
"url"         : "/black",
"source_host" : "www.jut.io",
"referer"     : "http://google.co.in/",
"space"       : "default",
"type"        : "event",
"time"        : "2014-12-11T23:46:21.905Z",
"mock_type"   : "demo",
"event_type"  : "web"
```

}

Comment: This is cool, but this wouldn't work on a group of events with different fields. How do I view all unique fields for a given program?

Comment: right; this only works for really structured data. There should be some other proc that does eactly this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split](http://docs.jut.io/juttle-reference/#split) proc in combination with [reduce by](http://docs.jut.io/juttle-reference/#reduce) to get this list.

```
emit -limit 1
|(
  put field1 = 1, field2 = 2;
  put field2 = 2, field3 = 3;
)| split // break each point into one point for each field, assigning each field name into the point's name field
 | reduce by name // get unique list of name field values
 | sort name
 | @logger

{"name":"field3"}
{"name":"field2"}
{"name":"field1"}
==============================================================
```